# Magento2: How to debug out of stock notification not working?

Tags: magento2, email, out-of-stock

I'm using the Luma theme in Magento 2.3.3, my other transactional emails are working properly. I've no idea how to start debugging it.

How could I start debugging this issue and what to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it checking following these steps:

- Check the DB table called **product_alert_stock** where you have all the alerts.
- Try to run the specific cron job called **catalog_product_alert** which sends the emails via [Magerun2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2), you can run it via `magerun sys:cron:run`.
- Check if you have some SMTP or email module installed (e.g. Mailchimp), you can disable it to check, and check its logs.
- Change the theme to Luma via admin.
- You can try to disable all the third-party modules to finish your tests.
- Run the `composer update` to check if it's some issue already fixed.

If you didn't find the issue after all these steps, probably the issue is on your server.